# Show there does not exist a certain holomorphic function with the unit disc?

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that there does not exist a holomorphic function $f$ on $D(0, 1)$ such that 
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) = \begin{cases}
1+\frac{2}{n} & \text{if $n$ even}\\
1 & \text{if $n$ odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Here $D(0,1) = \{z : |z| < 1 \} $.

My thoughts are to do this by contradiction, but I am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Look up the identity principle.

Comment: What would be $f'(0)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We must have $f(0)=1$ since $f$ is differentiable, and hence continuous, at $0$.
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{z\to0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0} = \text{some particular complex number, since $f$ is differentiable at $0$}.
$$

But if that limit exists, then it must be equal to both
\begin{align}
& \lim_{\text{even }n\to\infty}\frac{f(1/n)-f(0)}{1/n-0} \\[12pt]
\text{and} &\lim_{\text{odd }n\to\infty}\frac{f(1/n)-f(0)}{1/n-0}.
\end{align}
But those two numbers differ.

Comment: +$1$: Excellent explanation!

Comment: @Clayton : Thank you.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you!